# time.sleep() function in Python 3.3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to continuously run through a WHILE loop to check for a condition every fifteen minutes. When using time.sleep(900) it instead holds off on executing the WHILE loop initially for fifteen minutes and then ceases to run through once the condition is met.

I believe Python 2 used this function for this reason, does Python 3.3 not follow this anymore? If not, how would I indefinitely run through a while loop, even if the condition has been met?

Below is a snippet of my code currently:

```
if price_now == 'Y':
    print(get_price())
else:
    price = "99.99"
    while price > "7.74":
        price = get_price()
        time.sleep(5)
```

**Edit:** *Updated based on eandersson feedback.*

```
if price_now == 'Y':
    print(get_price())
else:
    price = 99.99
    while price > 7.74:
        price = get_price()
        time.sleep(5)
```

The `get_price()` function:

```
def get_price():
    page = urllib.request.urlopen("link redacted")
    text = page.read().decode("utf8")
    where = text.find('>$')
    start_of_price = where + 2
    end_of_price = start_of_price + 4
    price = float(text[start_of_price:end_of_price])
    return(price)
```

Comment: Updated your question to include the original code to prevent any confusion. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem in this case is that you are comparing a string, and not an float.

```
price = 99.99
while price > 7.74:
    price = get_price()
    time.sleep(5)
```

And you need to change the `get_price` function to return an float, or wrap it with `float()`

I even made a small test function to make sure and it works as intended with the sleep function.

```
price = 99.99
while price > 7.74:
    price += 1
    time.sleep(5)
```

**Edit:** `Updated based on comments.`

```
if price_now == 'Y':
    print(get_price())
else:
    price = 0.0
    # While price is lower than 7.74 continue to check for price changes.
    while price < 7.74: 
        price = get_price()
        time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks! I changed the get_price() function to include a float wrap instead of a string comparison, as well as changed price = and while price > to be integers rather than strings. I tested out the code by making time.sleep(5), but it still seems to run through once and then exit the loop.

Comment: And @KMcK what does get_price() return now during testing?

Comment: I updated the code to include the get_price() code, and when testing it returns the current (int) price from the from where it extracts the data.

Comment: Ok @KMcK . Keep in mind that `price > 7.74` means that the while statement will run while the data is higher than `7.74`. If get_price() returns a value lower than that it it will only execute once. Are you sure you don't want `price < 7.74`?

Comment: That is why I asked you what value you currently excepted get_price() to return.

Comment: Correct, I included price > 7.74 since I set the initial var to 99.99 to ensure the while loop runs at least once. When I set it to price < 7.74 it bypasses the while loop and skips right to the next lines. The price will generally never be higher than $10, should I lower my var threshold and change the conditional operator?

Comment: Yea. I would recommend that you set `price = float(0)` and then change the conditional operator.

Comment: Thanks for your help, your code worked great! But also after reverting back to my old code, for no explainable reason, the code began iterating through the while look indefinitely with no stops. Still trying to figure out what went differently so I know what to avoid next time.